# I want htaccess url rewrite script for static, dynamic & extension hiding url as well as their redirect method without loop problems

Tags: .htaccess, static

i am currently working on htaccess but facing some problems in rewriting static with dynamic with site extension hidden urls as well as their redirects so i need a complete script without loop problems and errors, also include different types of errors redirects...thanks

for example

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#FOR STATIC URLS
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ http://example.com/folder2/ [NC,L]

#FOR DYNAMIC URLS
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)\.php$ /folder2.PHP?ID=$1 [NC,L]

#FOR REDIRECTIONS
Redirect /old-url http://example.com/new-url
"and other necessary redirections to the new url that should be made as well as error  redirections to my home page"

#PHP EXTENSION REMOVING SCRIPT
```

hope this type of simple script help other beginners as well like me plz help

Comment: What's the problem you're facing with these rules, add some examples.

Comment: i have done all that mess with that method but i am facing loop error while redirecting urls old to new

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^old-url/?$ /new-url [L,NC,R=302]

#FOR STATIC URLS
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ /folder2/ [NC,L]

#FOR DYNAMIC URLS
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)\.php$ /folder2.PHP?ID=$1 [NC,L]
```

Keep redirects before rewrite rules and use only `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: thankx for helping now finally tell me redirect, when i redirect them it shows me loop error in browser, what would be the right method of redirections...

Comment: Use a different browser to test and use rules exactly as I have shown here.

Comment: hey Anubhava, i have done all above u told and new url is working but when i redirect it with this **Redirect old-url.php http://localhost/folder2** method it gives me **This webpage has a redirect loop** error in Chrome and **The page isn't redirecting properly** error in Firefox, tell me how to redirect after rewriting

Comment: No you cannot use any `Redirect` rules here. I clearly mentioned to use only `mod_rewrite` rules. Better you write clear requirements by editing your question.

Comment: OK kindly tell me how to do it with mod_rewrite and then perform how to redirect old url to new for search engines.

Comment: I have already told you that in my answer. If you post your full htaccess in your question then I can suggest further.

Comment: `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#FOR STATIC URLS
RewriteRule ^about-us-new/?$ about_us.php [NC,L]` now tell how to redirect it after doing that.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^about-us-new/?$ about_us.php [NC,L]` rule must be placed before `#FOR DYNAMIC URLS` line above.